# General formula of the derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $$g(z) = \frac{e^{zx}}{f(z)}$$ where $f(z) > 0$ for all $z$. Then $$g'(z) = \frac{f(z)xe^{zx}-e^{zx}f'(z)}{f^2(z)},$$ $$g''(z) = \frac{f^2(z)[f'(z)xe^{zx} + f(z)x^2e^{zx} - e^{zx}f''(x)-xe^{zx}f'(x)]-[f(z)xe^{zx}-e^{zx}f'(z)]2f(z)f'(z)}{f^4(z)},$$ and so on. What is the general formula of $g^{(n)}(z)$?

Comment: Why is this tagged under "polynomials?"

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Leibniz's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), namely
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}(f(x)g(x)) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {}_n \mathrm{C}_k f^{[n-k]}(x)g^{[k]}(x)$$
Where $g^{[k]}$ denotes the $k$th derivative of $g$, etc.
The function in question can be written as a product:
$$g(z)=e^{zx}\frac{1}{f(z)}$$
Assuming $x$ is a constant w.r.t $z$,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}z^k} e^{zx} = x^k e^{zx}$$
Now the tricky bit comes in computing
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}z^k} \frac{1}{f(z)}$$
But I hope you can take it from here.

**EDIT:**

So I gave this problem to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5En%2Fdx%5En+%281%2Ff%28x%29%29) and it came up with
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}z^k} \frac{1}{f(z)} = (k+1)\sum_{j=0}^{k} \frac{(-1)^j {}_k \mathrm{C}_j f^{[j]}(z) (f(z))^{-1-j}}{j+1}$$
Although I'm not sure where this comes from. Therefore it seems that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}z^n} \frac{e^{zx}}{f(z)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {}_n \mathrm{C}_k x^{n-k}e^{zx} (k+1)\sum_{j=0}^{k} \frac{(-1)^j {}_k \mathrm{C}_j f^{[j]}(z) (f(z))^{-1-j}}{j+1}$$
Yikes.

Note: ${}_a \mathrm{C}_b = \frac{a!}{(a-b)!b!}$.

Comment: Ok, I acknowledge that my answer is probably a bit sparse. But I would recommend perhaps asking MSE about the $n$th derivative of $1/f(x)$. I'm sure some very smart people would love to help.

Comment: If you want to actually solve the problem you will need Faa di Bruno’s formula. I disagree that one should ask that question as it’s essentially the same question as this one